# Считывание qr кодов

Tags: python

у меня проблема, есть ссылка с изображением qr кода, нужно считать этот qr код(там находятся числа) и вывести данные полученные из qr кода
Спасибо
Если нужно кину код
На вход подаётся ссылка, там расположен qr код, нужно обработать его и вывести информацию

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который у вас есть, изображением qr кода и еще раз расскажите что вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 0):

Я знаю как можно сделать такую штуку при помощи opencv-python в режиме реального времени(с веб камеры)

```
from cv2 import cv2 
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap.set(3, 360)
cap.set(4, 360)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    for code in decode(frame):
        data  = code.data.decode('utf-8')
        print(data)

    cv2.imshow('QrLinkDetection', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

При запуске данного кода у вас появиться окно транслирующие изображение вашей веб камеры, если вы покажете в веб камеру QrCode то в консоль вывудиться куда он ведёт(ссылку). Думаю это можно реализовать и с картинкой подобным образом...

Comment: К сожалению я это тоже знаю